# what is the best way to handle hybris default users (e.g importmanger for importcockpit).

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I have out of the box default hybris user (e.g importmanger for importcockpit), It has admin group permission. I do not want this user to exist in my system. But whenever essential data runs this user creates. how can I handle this user in my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an impex in one of your extensions where you delete this user.

For each environment, **if you have a lot of data you want to remove/modify**, you can create a specific extension with all your impex and only deploy it on the desired envrionment.